# Как передать значение аргумента в другой компонент по onClick

Tags: reactjs, циклы, onclicklistener

есть цикл, который формирует таблицу в React, необходимо по onClick вывести в консоль значения каждой итерации данного цикла, простыми словами - адрес ячейки, по которой кликнули мышкой. Сейчас в консоль выводится общее значение итераций. я понимаю, что для этого надо создать отдельный компонент, куда передать значение аргументов, но как это сделать - придумать не могу

```
  class Table extends Component{
  constructor (){
  super();
  this.cellClick = this.cellClick.bind(this);
  }
  cellClick () {
    console.log (i,j)
  }
  render(){
    var trs= new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.props.rows; i++) {
      var tds = new Array();
      for (var j = 0; j <= this.props.columns; j++) {
        tds.push (<td columns = {i} rows = {j} onClick = {this.cellClick}> 
        {i} x {j} </td>)
       }
      trs.push(<tr>{tds}</tr>)
     }
    return (
        <table>
          {trs}
        </table>
     )
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Быстрый, но считается антипаттерном:

```
cellClick = (i, j) => {
    console.log (i,j)
};
....
tds.push (
    <td columns = {i} rows = {j} onClick = {this.cellClick.bind(this, i, j)}> 
        {i} x {j} 
    </td>
)
```

Вариант 2. Сделать для td отдельный компонент:

```
class MyTd extends React.Component {
    onClick = () => {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.columns, this.props.rows);
    };

    render() {
        return <td onClick = {this.onClick}> 
            {this.props.children}
        </td>
    }
}

class Table extends Component{
  cellClick = (i, j) => {
    console.log (i,j)
  };

  render(){
    ....    
        tds.push (<MyTd columns = {i} rows = {j} onClick = {this.cellClick}> 
        {i} x {j} </MyTd>)
       }
    ....
   }
}
```

Comment: тот же результат получается: на какую бы ячейку я не кликнула, в консоли просто срабатывает счетчик кликов и i и j не меняются.

Comment: какой из вариантов пробовали?

Comment: для обоих вариантов уберите из конструктора this.cellClick = this.cellClick.bind(this);

Comment: и 1й, и 2й. Результат одинаковый - счетчик кликов.

Comment: да, так работает. Объясните, почему если объявляем this.cellClick = this.cellClick.bind(this, i, j) и при этом onClick = {this.cellClick} не работает, а если брать сокращенную запись onClick = {this.cellClick.bind(this, i, j), тогда работает. и еще вопрос по вар№2 - вы использовали {this.props.children} - т.к это дочерний компонент?

Comment: у вас обработчик биндился один раз в конструкторе. соответственно при этом обработчик ничего не знает про i, j. Конструкция cellClick(this, i, j) создает обертку при каждом рендере (от того и антипаттерн)

Comment: this.props.children - это все "подэлементы", которые вы поместите между <MyTd></MyTd>